# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID with Cloud front

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have an S3-hosted static website and a Cloud Front distribution. THere is an A record in Route 53 pointing to the Cloud Front distribution. When I created the distribution, I accepted the default setting for the certificate. That is, I did not enter a certificate ID or request a certificate. When I attempt to browse to the site with Chrome, I get NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID.

How can I view or modify the common name of the default certificate? It doesn't appear in Certificate Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not programming or development and may need to be deleted but:

1. to answer as asked:

   For *most* builds of curl (but not the Microsoft-supplied curl.exe on Windows, which uses schannel) `curl -v https://host` will display the subject and some other attributes of the (server/leaf) cert; the CN= part is the CommonName. Pretty much all Linux and most other Unix will have suitable curl preinstalled; on Windows you can either find and install a non-schannel build for Windows (which may not be so easy as it was when I was younger), or use WSL (which gives you a Linux build).

   If you have OpenSSL, `echo Q | openssl s_client -connect host:443` (for versions below 1.1.1 you may need to add `-servername host`) will show the subject and issuer names of *all* certs in the chain (as validated, which may differ from sent in the CA(s) but not the leaf); you want the '0 s:' line, or the repeated info at `Server certificate / subject=` a page or two down. Again nearly all Linuxes and Unixes have OpenSSL; for Windows you can get a port from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html or again use WSL. (Instead of `echo Q |` you can use `</dev/null` on Unix or `<NUL` on Windows.)

   If you have Java, `keytool -printcert -sslserver host` shows a *lot* of info about the cert chain; the first lines `Certificate #0 / ===== / Owner:` are the ones you want. 15 or 20 years ago when Java was considered the wave of the future it was available almost everywhere; today not so much. I wouldn't install Java just for this, but if you want it for any better reason(s), go for it.
2. but you don't want to.

   That error code in Chrome is very misleading. Decades ago it was the standard or at least usual convention to use (and verify) CommonName in Subject to be the server hostname. Since about 2010 all public CAs, and most others as well, switched to using the [SubjectAlternativeName aka SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) *extension* instead. Initially browsers continued to accept CommonName if SAN is absent, but since about 2017 Chrome *only* uses SAN and never ever looks at CommonName. So that error code now actually means *SAN* doesn't match *or is missing*; CommonName may well be correct, and even if it is wrong fixing it won't fix the Chrome error.
3. so how do you fix SAN in CloudFront? I can't help there.

Comment: I have Linux. The openssl command provided here gets is rejected by openssl. The command "openssl s_client -servername mydomain.com:443" results in Connection Refused

Comment: Your command runs successfully witn windows OpenSSL and it says "no peer certificate", "No client certificate names sent." Since I posted this, I switched to a custom certificate, so something should be there

Comment: Also "ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../openssl-1.1.1"

Comment: Anna: I said `-connect host:443` -- with the possible _addition_ of `-servername host` (no :443) but you don't need that since you apparently have 1.1.1. OpenSSL 1.1.1 shouldn't get 'wrong version' with an up-to-date server like cloudfront/AWS, unless you use the HTTP port (80) instead of the HTTPS port (443); if you can identify the domain I'll look at it. However if it does somehow get wrong version, the handshake fails and it can't get the certificate chain, so lack of displaying the certificate is entirely consistent.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in Cloud Front where you can put in the SAN - it's called "alternate domain name."

I had to examine the certificate to see that it didn't have mydomain.com as an alternate name - all it had was the domain name of the cloud front distribution.